# Downloading Xcode libraries with slow internet connection

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

I need to find the link to install the Xcode 4.3 developer library (237 MB) and the iOS 5.1 Library (Apple iPhone OS 5.1) (395 MB).

Since I have a slow internet connection, I am unable to download it from my Xcode, so I will have to download it from another machine and copy it to my Mac.

So, does anyone here know the direct link to the above downloads?

Note: I am running OS 10.7.3 and my Xcode version is 4.3.1.

Comment: I took a look around the developer site but there appear to be no links to the separate downloadable installers, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot do it, or at least not in a way that would pay off.

I would be much easier to go with your laptop to a McDonalds and get it from there.

Trust me, I've been there ;)

Answer (score 0):

One method that might work is to install xCode completely on a machine with a fast internet connection, then copy thedeveloper directory and a few other directories over to the new machine.  It'll be a bit tricky, but doable.